# slower running time with hybrid OpenMP/MPI vs OpenMP alone

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, openmp, openmpi

I am writing a hybrid openMP/MPI piece of code.
I first bench-marked the openMP alone on 8 threads.
Then, I added the MPI layer like the following

```
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &namelen);
//the following function has OPENMP for loop embedded
parallelfunction(args);//should I add condition on rank?
MPI_finalize();
```

The openMP function is a standard openmp for loop

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic,chunk) private(i)
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
//loop code here
}
```

I compiled the hybrid code and run it on one CPU like this

```
mpirun -np 1 -x OMP_NUM_THREADS=8 ./program
```

to only realize that running time was 5 times slower than openMP alone (on one CPU necessarily).
I benchmark the wall-time using bash `time` function.
Any suggestions?

I am using openmp 3.1 with mpicc

EDIT

I use openMPI v1.10.3

Comment: It is completely impossible to tell without seeing actual code and actual measurement results.

Comment: Yes indeed. 1 cpu and 8 threads.

Comment: You are clearly using Open MPI. Try adding `--bind-to none` to the list of `mpirun` options.

Comment: Per Zulan's comment above, provide the interior loop code and at least the runtime. If OMP+MPI, on one MPI process, is significantly slower than OMP alone then MPI initialization time is non-negligible with respect to the computation. If so, your `n` is too small for benchmarking. If `n` can't be changed then your parallelization model is just wrong.

Comment: As usual @HristoIliev saved the day! Thanks for the great help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't explicitly specified the MPI implementation, but using `-x` to pass environment variables to the MPI processes is a telltale sign of Open MPI. Starting with version 1.8, process pinning/binding is enabled by default as detailed in the man page of the [MPI process launcher](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.10/man1/mpirun.1.php):

> Please note that mpirun automatically binds processes as of the start of the v1.8 series. Two binding patterns are used in the absence of any further directives:
>
> **Bind to core:**
>   when the number of processes is <= 2
>   **Bind to socket:**
>   when the number of processes is > 2
>
> If your application uses threads, then you probably want to ensure that you are either not bound at all (by specifying `--bind-to none`), or bound to multiple cores using an appropriate binding level or specific number of processing elements per application process.

In your case the process gets bound to a single core and all threads have to timeshare on it. `--bind-to none` removes the binding and allows for threads to be scheduled on all CPU cores.